# Modular Application Design

Tags: xamarin.forms

We currently have an application that is usable by several clients, it is used to download and store data from our application that they have on their environment.

We have a need to pass this application over to a developer but at the same time, we need to protect our code.  The way that I see it working is that we would like to some how consider our current app a framework, allowing another app to be created on top of it, but the app may have its own screens, but re-use some of the built-in screens.

Is it possible to protect our app in such a way with out rewriting everything into protected DLL's?  Or should we just suck it up and share our code with consulting firms that want to build these types of apps for our clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your proprietary code is *entirely focused* on downloading and storing data. You could create an online REST api that returns the data over the internet. The other developer could then just request the data from your servers using an HTTP call.

However if your code needs to be client-side, the only real thing you can do is compile a DLL, and even then that can be decompiled.

Comment: This is exactly what I figured (the DLL part).  Thanks.  At least we are on the same page.